# Multiple context `with` statement in Python 2.6

Tags: python

I like the convenience of the multiple context `with` statement in Python 2.7:

```
with open('a.txt') as a, open('b.txt') as b:
   do_many_amazing_things(a, b)
```

However, I need to maintain compatibility with 2.6.

`with` was brought to 2.5 via `__future__`, but I am unable to find anything about the multiple context version being back-ported to 2.6 in the documentation.

Is there something I missed?

EDIT: I am aware that is possible to nest `with` statements.  I am asking if it's possible to use multiple with statements.

Comment: I'm actually surprised that this feature was added to Python - the guiding principle has always been to make things simple and obvious, but since nesting `with` statements is so natural...

Comment: It gets ugly if you're doing more than 2.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If no backward-compatible equivalent of this is possible, I would handle it by making the multiple-context `with` statement a set of single-context, nested `with` statements.

```
with open('a.txt') as a: 
    with open('b.txt') as b:
        do_many_amazing_things(a, b)
```

EDIT to address your edit:

If you insist on not nesting extra `with` statements, you can always use `contextlib`

```
import contextlib
with contextlib.nested(open("a.txt"), open("b.txt")) as (a, b):
    do_many_amazing_things(a,b)
```

As for using multiple `with` statements from the future-imported `with`, this isn't possible as far as I know

Comment: Won't the contextlib solution fail if the first file opens but not the second - the first file won't be closed?

Comment: @Mark Random I believe so, I should've mentioned that, but it's the closest thing I can find to Austin's intentions

Comment: I don't see why you say that the first file won't be closed. If writing it in one way is the same as the other, then the first file will close no matter how the execution flow got out of the first context.

Comment: @Gabriel this is a bug with contextlib.nested. Info: http://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.nested ->
"That means, for example, that using nested() to open two files is a programming error as the first file will not be closed promptly if an exception is thrown when opening the second file."